# Getting started with guppy wyswyg javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, math, plugins

Im trying to use guppy wyswyg javascript plugin for mathematical expressions rendering. I went to its basic example at its webpage https://guppy.js.org/site/examples/basic/, but i cant deploy it at my local xampp proyect.

According to the example, i already set these dependencies (different paths in my proyect):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="localhost/lib/build/guppy-default.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../build/guppy.min.js"></script>
```

And then this:

```
Guppy.init(
                {
                    "path":"http://localhost/lib/guppy",
                    "symbols":"http://localhost/lib/guppy/sym/symbols.json"
                }
    );
```

Finally this:

```
<input type="text" id="myinputtypeelementid"  placeholder="Type math here" >

var g1 = new Guppy("myinputtypeelementid");
```

[I just can see this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUq8z.png)
Does anybody know what else i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved:

It just needed use a `<div>` tag with the right id instead o a `<input>` tag. Now it works ! I reply myself in case anybody gets benefit of this issue i faced.